# Is it possible to animate views frame by frame continuously in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

So I am working on implementing a custom view on iOS which will animate with momentum.  This is something like the "wheel of fortune" wheel, where the user can flick it, and it will spin around with momentum, and eventually slow down and snap into place.

So I would like to have something like a "tick" function to update the view every frame (pseudocode):

```
// Function called on each animation frame
func tickAnimation(deltaTime: TimeInterval) {
    myView.rotateBy(deltaTime)
    ...
}
```

So the naiive way to do this would be to just have a timer:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0/60, repeats: true) { timer in
    tickAnimation(deltaTime: 1.0/60)
}
```

But is there a better way to do this, where I can hook directly into the iOS animation system and synchronize my updates with the screen refresh directly?

I.e. is there something similar to `Window.requestAnimationFrame()` which you have on web?

Comment: CADisplayLink is the thing you’re looking for to hook into the screen refresh.

Answer (score -1):

I found something exactly you want but there is no short answer for your question hence I drop a wheel of fortune [link](https://medium.com/@kiranmandalapu/fortune-wheel-in-swift-f1943767a442).

If you want something shorter than you should look for UIview.animate()

you can set time of duration, delay and animation style such as curveEaseIn, curveEaseOut etc. It could be helpful for your question.